# "(null) wants to access twitter" when using ACAccountStore

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, ios5

I'm using the Accounts framework from the iOS SDK to handle twitter requests. When my app requests permission from the user to access the twitter account, (null) is shown as the app name in the permission request alert.

What value do I need to set to make this show my actual app name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the value for `CFBundleDisplayName` in YourApp-Info.plist